# Is is possible to create 2 navbars without them overlapping on react?

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, material-ui

I want to create 2 navbars to be the header of my page, but when I try to implement they overlap.
I am trying to create something like this:

```
<>
<Grid direction='column'>
<Grid>
<Box>
<AppBar> <Toolbar>
</Toolbar>
</AppBar>
</Box>
</Grid>

<Grid>
<Box>
<AppBar> <Toolbar>
</Toolbar>
</AppBar>
</Box>
</Grid>

<Grid/>
</>
```

Where the second appbar is exactly below the first one and I can personalize them separately

Comment: Where `Grid` component come from? You make it by your own code or imported from another package library?

Comment: I imported it from material-ui/core

Comment: Can you give screenshot your result?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/8bgmekN The smaller bar is overlapping the Bigger one, I want them to stay one after another. Fixed

Comment: I think there is no problem with the `Grid` component, maybe on `AppBar` or `ToolBar` component, which you not included your code on the question above.

Comment: My code is here https://snipit.io/public/lists/18735/60697

Comment: can you use codesandbox.io? Your problem is on style/css

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-tdd-fvzvg?file=/src/components/navbar/Navbar.tsx

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.